# numpy.cov() exception: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, attributeerror

I have a dataset for different plant species, and I separated each species into a different `np.array`.

When trying to generate gaussian models out of these species, I had to calculate the means and covariance matrices for each different label.

The problem is: when using `np.cov()` in one of the labels, the function raises the error "'float' object has no attribute 'shape'" and I can't really figure out where the problem is coming from. The exact line of code I'm using is the following:

```
covx = np.cov(label0, rowvar=False)
```

Where `label0` is a numpy ndarray of shape (50,3), where the columns represent different variables and each row is a different observation.

The exact error trace is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-277aa1d02ff0> in <module>()
      2 
      3 # Get the covariances
----> 4 np.cov(label0, rowvar=False)

C:\Users\Matheus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in cov(m, y, rowvar, bias, ddof, fweights, aweights)
   3062             w *= aweights
   3063 
-> 3064     avg, w_sum = average(X, axis=1, weights=w, returned=True)
   3065     w_sum = w_sum[0]
   3066 

C:\Users\Matheus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in average(a, axis, weights, returned)
   1143 
   1144     if returned:
-> 1145         if scl.shape != avg.shape:
   1146             scl = np.broadcast_to(scl, avg.shape).copy()
   1147         return avg, scl

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Any ideas of what is going wrong?

Comment: `label0` seems to be a float rather than an array.

Comment: According to the documentation of [`np.cov`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html), the parameter should have one row per variable and one column per observation, not the other way around.

Comment: @COLDSPEED when I print the type of label0 ot says np.ndarray. Printing out the shape it says (50,3). So it's definitely not a float, but an array of floats haha

Comment: @jdehesa That's the default settings yes, one row per variable and one column per observation. However, if u read the documentation, you can pass rowvar=False if yoh have the transpose of the matrix described.

Comment: Just to be sure: what is `label0.dtype`?  A [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help--something that we can run to reproduce the error.

Comment: @MSeifert my laptop's battery just ran out! I will give you this info in a few minutes when I get to the hotel!

Comment: @Warren Weckesser you are right, the dtype is object and I will convert it to float! Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try

```
    label0.astype(float32)
```

and then calculate your cov.

It might because your dtype is object.

Comment: the float32 needs to be in quotes otherwise the code throws a NameError

Answer (score 31):

The error is reproducible if the array is of `dtype=object`:

```
import numpy  as np

label0 = np.random.random((50, 3)).astype(object)
np.cov(label0, rowvar=False)
```

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'

If possible you should convert it to a numeric type. For example:

```
np.cov(label0.astype(float), rowvar=False)  # works
```

Note: `object` arrays are rarely useful (they are slow and not all NumPy functions deal gracefully with these - like in this case), so it could make sense to check where it came from and also fix that.

Comment: Spot on! Someone else already replied with this fix, but since you gave it ad an answer I will update it.

Comment: *"... check where it came from ..."*  When in doubt, suspect Pandas.

Comment: @MatGomes I'm glad it worked. Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the most helpful answer if that answer resolved your issue.